# Verify, whether matrices form a basis for $\mathbb{R}_{2\times 2}$ and find coordinates in the basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying the solve the following problem:

> Verify, whether
>   matrices $A=\begin{pmatrix}  -1&1 \\   1&2  \end{pmatrix}$,
>   $B=\begin{pmatrix}  0&1 \\   1&0  \end{pmatrix}$, $C= \begin{pmatrix} 
> 1&1 \\   0&0  \end{pmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{pmatrix}  0&0 \\   1&2 
>  \end{pmatrix}$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}_{2\times 2}$. Also
>   find coordinates of matrix $E=\begin{pmatrix}  -2&2 \\   8&4 
>  \end{pmatrix}$ in the basis.

What I did was to create a matrix $F=$ $\begin{pmatrix}
 -1&0  &1  &0 \\ 
 1&1  &0  &1 \\ 
 1&1  &1  &0 \\ 
 2&0  &0  &2 
\end{pmatrix}$ and verify, whether there are any linearly dependent lines. I found out that there are none, therefore the matrices $A,B,C,D$ are generating the entire space and therefore they form a basis. Is my solution correct?

And how would I find the coordinates of the matrix E in the basis? Do I just put the numbers from the matrix $E$ as solutions in my matrix $F$? Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you supposed to find if the given matrices form the basis for $\mathbb{R}_{2}$?

Comment: @InMyOwnEuclideanspace no, it's $\mathbb{R}_{2\times 2}$

Comment: I think you might have mistakenly assumed that you need to find the basis for a four dimensional space, $\mathbb{R}_{2x2}$ does not mean that. What you need to do is figure out if each of the A,B,C and D matrices mentioned form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Comment: @InMyOwnEuclideanspace How would I do so? Sorry, it says $\mathbb{R}_{2\times 2}$ in the problem's description and I have never seen a problem like this, so I'm quite lost in this.

Comment: @InMyOwnEuclideanspace The matrices are not even elements of $\Bbb{R}^2$, so how an they form a basis? I think the OP's answer is correct (it is missing some details regarding the isomorphism he implicitly used between $\Bbb{R}_{2 \times 2}$ and $\Bbb{R}^4$) but the idea is correct.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, I was lost with his intention to figure out the basis for $\mathbb{R}_{2X2}$ with no isomorphism in place. The matrices are not elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$, of course, but I thought what was meant was whether their columns form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, which might be a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You found they form a basis.  Now you need to solve $aA+bB+cC+dD=E$ for $a,b,c$ and $d$.  This is a linear system of $4$ equations in $4$ unknowns. You could form another matrix to solve.

Here's the matrix: $\left(\begin {array}{rrrr|r}-1&0&1&0&-2\\1&1&1&0&2\\1&1&0&1&8\\2&0&0&2&4\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please show me an example how will the matrix look like? Do I just put the numbers from $E$ as a solution of my matrix $F$?

Comment: @james See my edit.

Comment: Thanks! One last question, why did you put $(-2,2,8,4)$ as a solution instead of $(-2,8,2,4)$? Does it matter whether I go put them by the columns or by the rows?

Comment: I did it in a different order than you.  But the order doesn't matter.  As long as you're consistent.  (You could switch the $2$nd and $3$rd row.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a basis $B = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, \dots\}$ and a corresponding matrix $M = [v_1, v_2, v_3, \dots]$, both expressed in the "standard" basis, then the inverse of this matrix is the change-of-basis matrix from the standard basis to $B$. So, you just need to find the inverse of the matrix $F$ and multiply by $\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 8 \\ 2 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}$. This will give you a column vector version of the matrix in the correct basis.

Answer (score 0):

Your method for proving that $A,B,C,D$ form a basis for the set of matrices $\Bbb{R}_{2 \times 2}$ is correct, but perhaps you could benefit from a little more justification. What you have done is to "stack the matrix as a column vector". More precisely, this means you have constructed a linear isomorphsim $\Phi: \Bbb{R}_{2 \times 2} \to \Bbb{R}^4$ defined by the rule
\begin{align}
\Phi
\begin{pmatrix}
a & c \\
b & d
\end{pmatrix} &=
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

You were asked to verify whether the set 
\begin{equation}
\alpha = \{A,B,C,D\}
\end{equation}
forms a basis for $\Bbb{R}_{2 \times 2}$. Since $\Phi$ is an isomorphism, this is equivalent to checking whether
\begin{equation}
\Phi[\alpha] = \{\Phi(A), \Phi(B), \Phi(C), \Phi(D)\}
\end{equation}

forms a basis of $\Bbb{R}^4$. What you have done next is to create a new matrix $F$ whose columns are $\Phi(A), \dots \Phi(D)$. After this, you verified that these four columns are linearly independent. Thus, you found $4$ linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb{R}^4$, which means they form a basis. Therefore, $\alpha = \{A,B,C,D\}$ does indeed form a basis of $\Bbb{R}_{2 \times 2}$.

This is a more complete explanantion of why your method of "stacking matrices as column vectors" and checking whether the $4$ columns are independent/dependent actually works.